# How to fix "Error executing DDL alter table _____ modify column ___ bigint not null auto_increment "

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

So, i've been looking for a fix to this problem for a bit:

```
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "alter table ____ modify column xxxx_id  bigint not null auto_increment" via JDBC [Referencing column 'fk_xxxx_id' and referenced column 'xxxx_id' in foreign key constraint 'fk_yyyy_xxxx' are incompatible.]
```

My application.propierties is:

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

And the two classes involved (just the part where i think i have the problem):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "xxxxs")
public class yyyyEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long xxxx_id;

    private String name;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "registration_date")
    private Date registrationDate;

    @Column(name = "success_rate")
    private Double successRate;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "xxxx", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<yyyyntity> yyyys;
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "yyyys")
public class yyyyEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long yyyy_id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_xxxx_id", referencedColumnName = "xxxx_id")
    private xxxxEntity xxxx;
```

I've checked multiple times the names on the tables and on the Enities as well as the other tags

I've tried to change the names on both sides (DB and code), restart the database, and change the parameters of the foreign key to not have anything when before i had it marked as not null as it is necessary for it to be not null in how its supposed to work.

So far nothing has worked and the only thing that changes on the error message are the names of the columns

Comment: 'Referencing column 'fk_xxxx_id' and referenced column 'xxxx_id' in foreign key constraint 'fk_yyyy_xxxx' are incompatible.' - is clear..what are the respective datatypes?

Comment: Could it be because of the type in here? `private List<yyyyntity> yyyys;` It should be `private List<yyyyEntity> yyyys;` I don't think your code will even compile